# How to synchronously call async method from quartz schedule job

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am trying to call a webapi method from my quartz.net schedule job. I am not sure whether the way I am doing is right? Can anyone help if this is the right way or is there any better approach available?

MethodRepository.cs

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ResultClass>> GetResult(string queryCriteria)
{
    return await _httpClient.Get(queryCriteria);
}
```

Quartz job:

```
public async void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var results= await _repo.GetResult();
}
```

generic Httpclient :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get(string queryCriteria)
{
    _addressSuffix = _addressSuffix + queryCriteria;
    var responseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_addressSuffix);
    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>();
}
```

But the quartz documentation says I can't use async method in a quartz job. How can one the Web API method then?

Can I change the quartz job execute method as:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var result = _repo.GetResult().Result;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to do it - then yes you can do that, but it will block the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete.

[Task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) will wrap any exception into an AggregateException.

So you should probably put your httpclient call in a try catch.

```
  try
  {
      var result = _repo.GetResult().Result;
  }
  catch (AggregateException ae)
  {
      // handle exception
  }
```

Also, it seems they are working on an [AsyncJob](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/quartznet-3/src/Quartz.Examples/example16/AsyncJob.cs).

Comment: It is not a good idea to catch all exceptions until you really need it (and can handle something like `OutOfMemoryException`). Even worse is to filter and re-throw some of them or some of nested ones. You can easly avoid this with  `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` method, that could help you to get rid of `AggregateException` and work with original exceptions.

Comment: Sure. Just calling out that Task.Result raises AggregateException - nothing more.

Comment: @lorond, according to [Quartz Best Practices](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/best-practices.html) you actually _should_ handle all exceptions inside the job, so I think it counts as "really need it".

Answer (score 24):

[Quartz.NET 3.0](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2017/12/30/quartznet-3-0-released/) supports async/await out of the box. So you can (and must) now declare Execute method as Task returning and you can use async/await.

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var result = await _repo.GetResult();
}
```